# focus on required fields in Asp.Net Tab Control in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, required, required-field

net application, in that i have many required field text boxes in Tabcontrol in both tab panels.

when i have clicked submit button, it only focus current tab text box controls, 
but when i filled all the current tab panel controls then press submit button,
i want to focus the next tab panel text box which is empty,

but it can't focus on another tab panel textbox.

i don't know how to focus this, please any body let me know.

```
required="required"
```

[image]

[image]

```
<td><asp:Label ID="lblCustomerMobileNo" runat="server" Text="Customer Mobile No" CssClass="label"></asp:Label></td>

<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomerMobileNo" runat="server" CssClass="smalltextbox" PlaceHolder="Customer Mobile No" Width="100px" MaxLength="10" OnKeypress="javascript:return onlyNumbers(event,this.value);"
required="required" /> </td>
```

when i am in TAB 4, i press save button it focus required text box.

but i filled customer mobile no, and then press save button TAB 0 also having some required field text boxes but its not focus..

Comment: code..........?

Comment: @Imad updated, pls check..

Comment: How are you switching tabs?

Comment: by using mouse click only.. i need focus which field is required in another tab panel.

Comment: of course by mouse but I am asking about code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript function to check fields and focus in tab which has empty field.
or in server side check fields and set active tab

Answer (score 0):

If you use the build-in aspnet Validation Controls, you have the `SetFocusOnError` property.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="Field is required" ValidationGroup="myForm" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
    SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="myForm" />
```